# To find $f'(x)$ when $f(x) = \sqrt{\sin^{-1}x+\sqrt{\cos^{-1}x+\sqrt{\sin^{-1}x+\sqrt{\cos^{-1}x+\cdots\infty}}}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, recursion, chain-rule

> If
> $$
> f(x) = \sqrt{\sin^{-1}x + \sqrt{\cos^{-1}x + \sqrt{\sin^{-1}x + \sqrt{\cos^{-1}x + \cdots\infty}}}},
> $$
> then how to find $\frac{d}{dx}(f(x))$?

I am trying this question by taking $f(x)=y$.

Now
$$ 
y = \sqrt{\sin^{-1}x + \sqrt{\cos^{-1}x + \sqrt{\sin^{-1}x + \sqrt{\cos^{-1}x + \cdots\infty}}}}
$$

So, from this we can clearly see that $y=\sqrt{\sin^{-1}x+\sqrt{\cos^{-1}x+y}}$.

Now we can write that $y^{2}=\sin^{-1}x+\sqrt{\cos^{-1}x+y}$.

I am facing problem to find the derivative of $f(x)$. Please help me out.

Comment: Have you heard of implicit differentiation?

Comment: Did you try taking log both sides and then eliminating y from RHS

Comment: Taking log on both sides and differentiating is also not working.

Comment: Can you show for me the full solution @NinadMunshi .

Comment: @SyamaprasadChakrabarti no. I forgave it earlier since you were a new poster, but I am not a fan of your low effort posts with questions bordering on spam from questionable sources and no context.

Comment: And also who have downvoted this question, he also don't know how to solve. I think he got afraid by just seeing the question only.

Comment: Also I have shown my effort@NinadMunshi. Can you show that I have not shown my effort? Now why are you getting afraid to show your effort?

Comment: @SyamaprasadChakrabarti please read [this](https://www.ucale.com/differentiation-of-infinite-series/) for better understanding

Answer (score 3):

Differentiate the last equation you wrote in to order to get :
$$
2yy' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} + \frac{y'-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}{2\sqrt{y+\arccos x}}
     = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\left(1-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y + \arccos x}}\right) + \frac{y'}{2\sqrt{y+\arccos x}}
$$
Next, isolate $y'$ :
$$
y' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \frac{1-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y+\arccos x}}}{2y-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y+\arccos x}}} 
   = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \frac{1-2\sqrt{y+\arccos x}}{1-4y\sqrt{y+\arccos x}} 
$$
You can still work on this expression by replacing $\sqrt{y+\arccos x}$ by $y^2 - \arcsin x$ for instance, but basically you are done.